# Alfresco in Tomcat: OutOfMemory

Tags: tomcat, memory, jvm, alfresco

I've recently installed Alfresco 4.0d, with the 32 bit executable.

Whenever someone accesses the application, I get OutOfMemory error.

I've googled it and saw that more memory needs to be added.

So, I've tried editing the setenv.bat file in Alfresco's tomcat, like this:

```
set JAVA_HOME=D:\Alfresco\java
set JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xss1024K -Xms1G -Xmx2G -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -XX:NewSize=512m
```

However, the error still occurs.

I notice in the task manager that tomcat6.exe doesn't use more than 960mb, so my options aren't applied to it?

Regards,
Nuno.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you installed Alfresco community using the executable, it is likely that you are running Alfresco as a service. In order to update the JVM parameters when tomcat/Alfresco has been installed as a service navigate to your tomcat/bin directory and run the following as an Administrator:

```
C:\Alfresco\tomcat\bin>tomcat6w.exe //ES//alfrescoTomcat
```

This will bring up a small, tabbed window. Click on the "Java" tab and under the "Java Options:" text box enter your desired options, ie:

```
-Xms128M
-Xmx1536M
-Dalfresco.home=C:\Alfresco
```

Hit apply and restart your service. If you tail the logs (cygwin) you will see something like:

```
Alfresco JVM - v1.6.0_27-b07; maximum heap size 1365.375MB
```

The OOTB setting for the service can be found in the service.bat. These are the options used when the Alfresco installer creates the service. For more information on running Alfresco as a service see:
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Windows_Service_HOW-TO.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid, in fact you cannot have -Xmx2G on java 32bit, maybe your setting gets ignored?

Look here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit

"On most modern 32-bit Windows systems the maximum heap size will range from 1.4G to 1.6G. "

Comment: I've tried changing the settings to -Xms1G -Xmx1.5G but nothing changes. It is still stuck to 960mb. Here is my memory usage just before the OutOfMemoryError:http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/9940/memoryusage.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Out Of Memory Erorr is related with PermGem size. According to Alfresco wiki the recommended value is 256M (-XX:MaxPermSize:256m). Use recommended JVM setting for Alfresco if you do not have specific Alfresco installation http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/JVM_Tuning#General_Case

You can add your changes in ***catalina.bat*** file. If you are using Alfresco as Windows Service follow ConsultStan's instructions.

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat,find in \apache-tomcat-7.0.37\bin

I edited catalina.bat to add the following line:

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M

and

I edited catalina.sh

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"

it worked for e

helpful ;)